# Windows 10 clipboard history is not working with VMWare VDI

Tags: clipboard, vdi

I'm using a Windows 10 laptop to connect to a Windows 10 [VDI](https://www.vmware.com/products/horizon.html).  I have enabled "clipboard history" (in win 10 settings) on both.  But when I am "in" the VDI and hit Logo+V it does not show the correct list.  It shows the clipboard history from the non-VDI only.

I was expecting (hoping) the clipboard history can be shared between the two computers (VDI and non-VDI).  How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing vmvare tools
(when you start vm) VM menu -> install vmvare tools

that sholud solve problem with resolution (if u have it)
and with clipboard

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install VMWare Tools but it failed.

So I just installed [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) and then assigned hot-key Ctrl-Shift-V.  Works awesome!